# Is this set (average of components below some value) closed?

Tags: general-topology

I guess the question is rather basic, however I would appreciate an explaination.

Given a value $c\in\mathbb{R}$, I define the set $B\subset\mathbb{R}^\infty$:
$$ B:=\{(x_1,x_2,\dots):\sum_{i\geq1}(c-x_i)\geq 0\}$$

now is the set $B$ closed in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$? (with respect to the metric induced by the maximum-norm $\|x\|_\infty$)

Comment: What metric are you using on $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$?

Comment: The one induced by the $L^\infty$ norm

Comment: The sum may not converge, are you assuming that such elements are not in $B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x_i\mapsto c-x_i$ is an isometry of $\Bbb R^\infty$, we can equivalently ask if $B'=\{x\in\Bbb R^\infty\mid\sum_ix_i\ge 0\}$ is closed.

It is not closed. Consider the sequence $x_i=-2^{-i}$, so that $\sum_ix_i=-1$, hence $x\notin B'$. For any $n$, we can also consider the sequence $(y_n)_i=x_i+1/n$ if $i\le n$ and $(y_n)_i=x_i$ otherwise. This is also a convergent sequence, and $\sum_i(y_n)_i=\sum_ix_i+\sum_{i=1}^n1/n=0$, but $\|x-y\|_\infty\le1/n$. Thus $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of elements in $B'$ which converge to $x\notin B'$.

It is closed in the $\ell_1$ norm, however. (Note that $B$ itself will be empty for all $c\ne0$, because if $\sum_ix_i$ converges then $\sum_i(c-x_i)$ does not. But the question does make sense for $B'$, and the map $x_i\mapsto-x_i$ is an $\ell_1$ isometry, so $B$ is closed for $c=0$ iff $B'$ is closed.) If $x\notin B$, then $\sum_ix_i$ converges to some $-\epsilon<0$. But then for any $y\in\ell_1$ such that $\|x-y\|_1<\epsilon$, we have $\epsilon>\sum_i(y_i-x_i)=\sum_iy_i-\sum_ix_i=\sum_iy_i+\epsilon$, so $\sum_iy_i<0$ and hence $y\notin B'$.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question! I was just wondering if it was closed if we considered the same set $B\subset \mathbb{R}^+$, i.e. excluding negative values? Also I'd really like to upvote your answer but it seems I need 15 reputation to do so, so I'll do that as soon as possible.

Comment: @ssbm If we exclude negative values to get the set $\ell_\infty^+$ of bounded nonnegative sequences, then $B'=\ell_1^+$, the set of nonnegative convergent sequences. A counterexample in this case is the point $x_i=1/i$, which does not converge (so it is not in $B'$), but the initial segment $(y_n)_i=x_i$ if $i\le n$ and $(y_n)_i=0$ otherwise satisfies $\|x-y_n\|_\infty\le1/n$ but $y_n$ converges and so $y_n\in B'$.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I just read your comment asking whether or not to exclude non-convergent sequences. Actually I don't want to exclude non-convergent sequences, the set $B$ is exactly as I described it above. I see that the counterexample for the $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ case still works, but what about the $(\mathbb{R}^+)^\infty$ case?

Comment: @ssbm The problem is that the set $B$ as you described it makes no sense. If $(x_i)$ is not convergent, then $\sum_ix_i$ is not a number, so it doesn't make sense to say $\sum_ix_i\ge0$. The interpretation of $\sum_ix_i\ge0$ I have been using in this answer is that $\sum_ix_i$ converges to some $\ell\ge0$. You could also weaken this slightly to include sums that "converge" to $\infty$, but it is not clear at all what to do with sequences like $(-1,1,-1,1,\dots)$ - is the sum of the sequence $\ge0$ or not?

Comment: For nonnegative sequences, the sequence must always converge to some $\ell\in[0,\infty]$, so this problem goes away, and the only question is whether it is $\infty$ or not. If you are allowing sequences that converge to $\infty$ in the set $B$, then it is the whole set $\ell_\infty^+$ so of course it is closed.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! This helps me a lot! :)